# How can I accept JSON requests from a Kendo UI data source in my MVC4 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am using the Kendo UI grid in my MVC3 application and am quite pleased with it. I am using a Telerik provided example, excerpt below, to format the data posted by the grid's DataSource ally, and all is good. However, I don't want to have to rely on code like this. I would like to get Kendo and MVC talking without the 'translator', i.e. this code:

```
parameterMap: function(data, operation) {
    var result = { };
    for (var i = 0; i < data.models.length; i++) {
        var model = data.models[i];
        for (var member in model) {
            result["models[" + i + "]." + member] = model[member];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This function is a 'hook' that allows me to manipulated `data` before Kendo ajaxes it out. By default, the Kendo DataSource sends content-type form-encoded, but not quite right for the MVC model binder. Without this, I can still use a FormCollection and do my own binding, but that is not on.

When I configure the `DataSource` to send JSON, and change my mapping function to look like this

```
parameterMap: function(data, operation) {
    return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

I get the following data being send in the request, but now I have no idea how to get MVC to bind to this. Right now my only hope is to grab Request.Params[0] in the action method, and deserialize this JSON myself.

I don't think I should have to write any code to get two HTTP endpoints to communicate properly using JSON in this day and age. What am I doing wrong, or, what should I be looking at on my side, i.e. the receiver of the requests. I would really prefer to minimize my intervention on the client side to maybe just the `stringify` call.

Answer (score 1):

No idea if this is still a problem or not since this is a rather old question, but I had a scenario where I was shipping up json data to my controller and I had to give it a "hint" on what the name was so that model binding would work correctly:

```
public JsonResult GetDatByIds([Bind(Prefix="idList[]")]List<Guid> idList)
```

In my scenario, kendo was serializing my data and giving it a name of `idList[]` in the form post rather than just `idList`.  Once I gave it the model binding hint, it worked like a charm.  This might be the same for your scenario.

Comment: I'll need to resurrect that project to check this out, but it might help, thanks.