# Is there something I can use to neatly visualise JavaScript objects in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, javascript

I am a seasoned C# coder, but quite the JavaScript novice, and I am now trying to get a pure JavaScript component, the very competent Kendo UI DataSource, to talk nicely to my C# MVC3/4 controllers.* I would like to be able to examine certain JavaScript objects so I can fine tune my client side model mapping code, but the view of objects in the Chrome debugging console is a little cluttered and low level.

Is there a Chrome add-in I can use for visualising JavaScript objects while debugging script, and failing that, a nice object visualizer that I can use to output object visualizations as HTML. I can then toggle whether this is active, built a visual object graph for a debugging session, then switch the visualiser off again for normal operations in my client scripts.

** This question is a much broader and differently targetted one that shares only the same goal of my other question, [How can I accept JSON requests from a Kendo UI data source in my MVC4 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240422/how-can-i-accept-json-requests-from-a-kendo-ui-data-source-in-my-mvc4-applicatio) However, that question is more technology specific and covers the whole client-server roundtrip, where this one is specific to only visualising JavaScript objects on the client.

**EDIT:**
Based on suggestions below, `console.log` does provide adequate output for runtime inspection, but often the console is a busy place, and I would prefer to output a persistent visualization elsewhere, with all properties in the object expanded, but without the 'internals' e.g. __id and __proto, as seen in the image. I would just like to see `models` as an array of two objects, each with only Id and Name properties.

[image]

Comment: console.log(var); works pretty well

Comment: If you cannot find your object in the console, there's a problem. You should try to avoid making your console too busy and use it only when needed (mostly while debugging) : the console may take a lot of CPU and RAM if you abuse it.

Comment: If the console is too busy, you could use `console.warn` and filter to see warning messages, at the bottom of the developer log pane.  It's a gross abuse of the `warn` function, but this is just for debugging, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it more useful to send the object to the console than inspect it inside the debugger.  It's less cluttered and you don't have to go searching through your code for a breakpoint.  If you just do a `console.log(object)`, then hit F12 and select the Console, your object will be sitting there ready to be inspected.

**Edit**

If you do a `console.log` on the `models` property, it will come out like this:

[image: The Chrome console, after console.log 'ing an array of objects]

Or, if you prefer, you could use something like this to spit out the information without you having to click any arrows:

```
function logModels(models) {
    for (o in models) for (p in models[o])
            console.log(p +'\t' + models[o][p]);
}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: The Chrome console, after running a custom logging function]

You can also filter the console to only display `Logs` by clicking the appropriate button at the bottom of the bar.

Comment: Please see my edit. Looking for a tiny bit more than console output, but I can live with only this for now.